# Как деплоить приложение?

Tags: python, развертывание, devops

Подскажите как правильно и просто деплоить приложение (возможно скинуть где почитать или видос)
У меня есть rest api на django, react, postgress и я хочу запустить это все на хостле но не совсем понимаю как сделать это.

1. Залить ли все на один хост и разбить на порты или запускать все на разных  машинах?
2. Какой тип хоста выбрать?
3. Нужен ли какой то прокси типо nginx/gunicorn
4. Могу ли использовать как первый хост heroku или он не подойдет для таких целей
5. Где и как хранить db?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Разворачивание

Comment: Я очень люблю паковать всё в `Docker`, разбивая на отдельные сервисы. Запускаю на одном хосте.